# Is there a way to know the historic balance post every transaction in UTXO model such as Corda

Tags: corda

Need to build token exchange system which involves issue, transfer, redeem.
The ask is to show the node's historic balance per transaction using transaction history. The UTXO model does not store balance anywhere which does not help

The thought process here is that if we can calculate each nodes balance and store in same transaction involved in token exchange that can help in showing historic balance per transaction.

Lets take an example of transfer, since both nodes need to calculate individual balances, it can't be part of same atomic transaction as one node does not know anything about others balance as it is private data.

And if we try to calculate balance post token exchange commit to the ledger its not atomic and there is no way to roll back token exchange transaction, more over since state machine is not single threaded this could lead to race conditions and errors.

What is the best possible design keeping in mind token ledger as SVT

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think your understanding of unspent transaction output is accurate.

Think more about how the transactions affect the nodes.

Within Corda, every state object is kept within the nodes that utilize the object, so you can always see the latest state, and previous states of loans and things like that as long as your Corda state object can correctly keep track of it.

Take a look at the IOU Cordapp sample and you'll see a sample cordapp that should be meaningful for your use case: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp

Note specifically the IOUState and see how this object can outline the entire history of a loan.

```
public class IOUState implements ContractState, LinearState {

    public final Amount<Currency> amount;
    public final Party lender;
    public final Party borrower;
    public final Amount<Currency> paid;
    private final UniqueIdentifier linearId;
```

Source : https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/contracts/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/states/IOUState.java